# Edit Data with pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have a table with over 5 million records.

The view/edit data allows you to get all or first 100 or last 100 rows.

How do I select a specific row to edit?

Comment: I Recommend on you using  Navicat.

Comment: In any case, I cannot edit any records, even of these...

Comment: Navicat is $299US

Comment: Seems simple to access the records. Navigate via .. public + tables and in your case set a filter same as an sql "where". I double click a field and get an edit field with save or cancel. It doesn't appear to save which could be a problem if its more than just my settings. Anyhow I'd never use this feature, someone else might be able to add the missing info about how to save the data changes

Comment: Needs a pgadmin tag on this question

Answer (score 3):

In the Top-bar of pgAdmin, Under the Tools-Tab (1), click on QueryTool (2), and then write your SQL-Query (3) and execute it (4), for instance :

```
 SELECT id, arch_db FROM public.myTable WHERE id=6349
```

In the resulting record / row, double click on the field content (5), after having modified it (6), click on the OK button (7), and after having finished editing the fields content of this record, in the menu above your SQL-Query : click on the 4th icon (8) having the label onmousehover : "Save Data changes (F6)"
[image]

Comment: this picture is so cool!